# Confused about special character $ in a bash script

Tags: bash, command-line

I'm a beginner trying to learn bash script and I came across this snippet of a reference code and have no clue what it means because of all the $. Can anyone explain this to me?

```
    for i in $(seq $1 1 $2)
    do
    mkdir /for/july23/$$_$i
        cd $i
    origin=$PWD
```

Comment: `$` usually denotes the start of a substitution of some kind. `$(cmd)` substitutes output of running command `cmd`; `$1`,`$2` substitute the value of first and second arguments that were passed in; `$$` substitures the process id; `$i` substitutes the value of variable `i`; `$PWD` substitutes the process's working directory.

Comment: For `$1` and `$2` see the section _Positional Parameters_ in the bash man-page. For `$$`, see the section _Special Parameters_. for `$i` the section _Parameter Expansion_, for `$PWD` the section _Shell Variables_ and for `$(...)` the section _Command Substitution_. It's really worth reading these parts of the man-page; you will find many goodies which will be helpful when writing scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the first expression `$(seq $1 1 $2)`, it runs the command `seq` in a subshell with the `$()` syntax.

If you type `man seq` on your terminal you get the following information:

```
NAME
       seq - print a sequence of numbers

SYNOPSIS
       seq [OPTION]... LAST
       seq [OPTION]... FIRST LAST
       seq [OPTION]... FIRST INCREMENT LAST
```

So `seq` when used with three arguments, generates numbers from `FIRST`to `LAST`, with an offset equal to `INCREMENTS`.
So if you do `seq 1 2 10`, you'll get the sequence 1 3 5 7 9. Since in your code the increment is 1, it could be replaced by `seq $1 $2`, which would yield the same values, since the default increment is already `1`.

Now for the line `mkdir /for/july23/$$_$i`, here you have two variables used to create a directory, the first `$$` is the unique process id [pid](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/what-are-unix-pids-and-how-do-they-work/), and the other, `$i` is the current number in the sequence inside your for loop.

The line with `cd $i` changes the directory with that name, it fails if the directory `$i` does not exist.

And lastly, `origin=$PWD`assigns the value of a variable called `PWD` to a new one called origin. In bash, the command `pwd` refers to the current directory, so that is probably what the value of `PWD` is.

Answer (score 0):

The `$(seq $1 1 $2)` introduces command substitution. It is replaced with the output of the command itself.

The `$1`, `$2`, `$i`, `$$` and `$PWD` introduces parameter expansion. It is replaced with the value of the parameter.

So the code loop through each number on the output of `seq $1 1 $2`, creates the directory `/for/july23/$$_$i`, changes the working directory to `$i` and set the value of parameter `origin` to `$PWD`.